# How to subtract values of Dictionary if size is different and print negative values

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using this dictionary comprehension  **dict2={key:a[key]-b.get(key,0) for key in a}**
but not getting desired output

```
a={'x'=3,'y'=4}
b={'x'=1,'y'=2,'z'=3}
c=a-b 

desired output={'x'=2,'y'=2,'z'=-3}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
keys=list(a)
keys.extend(x for x in b if x not in a)
dict2={key:a.get(key,0)-b.get(key,0) for key in keys}
```

or one-liner

```
dict2 = {key:a.get(key,0)-b.get(key,0) for key in list(a) + [x for x in b if x not in a]}
```

Comment: thanks but one thing here order of dictionary changed after this comprehension what can I do for same order of key and value in dict2

Comment: updated the answer. Basically you can create a merged list of keys and then build the output dictionary using that.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {'x': 3, 'y': 4}
a.setdefault('z', 0)

b = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}

desired_output = {k1: v1 - v2 for k1, v1 in a.items() for k2, v2 in b.items() if k1 == k2}
```

Output:

```
{'x': 2, 'y': 2, 'z': -3}
```

**EDIT:** In case you dont know which keys are missing:

```
for k1, v1 in b.items():
    if not k1 in a.keys():
        a.setdefault(k1, 0)
```

Comment: what I can use instead of z if dont know the values of key of another dictionary for setting default value